# how to rate values at the same time

Tags: java

i need an advice how to do this program be in possible. I manage to make the program of user inputs(double format numbers) but I'm having trouble if how could i rate all values at the same time as i hit enter if it is "severe" or "normal".

suppose i enter

```
 2.2
 3.7
 3.9
```

output should be like this

```
 normal
 severe
 severe
```

heres my code

```
 Scanner dd = new Scanner(System.in);
 double[] vars = new double[3];

 for (int i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
 vars[i] = dd.nextDouble();
 if (vars[i] <3){
        System.out.println("normal");
      } 
 else if (vars[i] < 4){
   System.out.println("severe");

 }
 }
```

output of this is like this

```
2.2
normal
3.7
severe
3.9
severe
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)
```

Comment: not quite sure i understand the question

Answer (score 0):

You should put it in another for loop below the first one, once you take the inputs

```
Scanner dd = new Scanner(System.in);
double[] vars = new double[3];

for (int i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
   vars[i] = dd.nextDouble();
}

for (int i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
 if (vars[i] <3){
        System.out.println("normal");
 } 
 else if (vars[i] < 4){
   System.out.println("severe");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply move your printing logic to another loop and execute it after everything is read:

```
    Scanner dd = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] vars = new double[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        vars[i] = dd.nextDouble();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        if (vars[i] < 3) {
            System.out.println("normal");
        } else if (vars[i] < 4) {
            System.out.println("severe");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
 vars[i] = dd.nextDouble();
}

for (int i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    if (vars[i] <3){
        System.out.println("normal");
    } 
    else if (vars[i] < 4){
        System.out.println("severe");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are asking values at a time & at same time you are checking it & print it but instend of that what you can do you can ask all values at same time , store in array  & then check it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
    Scanner dd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your 3 values: \n");
    double[] vars = new double[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        vars[i] = dd.nextDouble();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        if (vars[i] < 3) {
            System.out.println("normal");
        } else if (vars[i] < 4) {
            System.out.println("severe");
        }
    }
```

Out put for your inputs.

```
    normal
    severe
    severe
```